# Copy files from source to target location conditionally inside rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I would like to copy some files from the source location to target location conditionally(based on the target system's version) inside the maven-rpm-plugin.

I tried it in the post install script, but the source location is not being accessed as it is not packaged.

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve by copying these files?

Comment: Based on the target system version, I would like to copy source file to the target location. How to do that in maven rpm plugin

Comment: That did you say. But for what purpose?

Comment: If you have different target systems you have to make different modules with a configuration for rpm-maven-plugin or make several executions of it...